MudSelect items not displaying
My problem is that MudSelect doesn't show the items...
I have this render mode in my App.razor:
<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

and I can click on the up arrow to up the number of an MudInputNumer and it is working, so I think the render mode is working.
I try the MudSelect on a compiler online and it is working fine...
Do you have any idea?
This is the complete page CommentVerse:
CommentVerse
@page "/CommentVerse"

@inject IJerusalemBibleService JerusalemBibleService

<EditForm Model="@model" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <MudGrid>
        <MudItem xs="12" sm="7">
            <MudCard>
                <MudCardContent>
                    <MudTextField T="string" Label="Verset(s)" Variant="Variant.Text" Text="@model.Verses" @bind-Value="model.Verses" Lines="10" />
                    <MudTextField T="string" Label="Commentaire" Variant="Variant.Text" Text="@model.Comment" @bind-Value="model.Comment" Lines="10" />
                </MudCardContent>
                <MudCardActions>
                    <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ml-auto">Ajouter</MudButton>
                </MudCardActions>
            </MudCard>
        </MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="12" sm="5">
            <MudPaper Class="pa-4 mud-height-full">
                <MudText Typo="Typo.subtitle2">Rechercher un verset</MudText>

                @if (InProgress)
                {
                    <MudProgressCircular Color="Color.Primary" Indeterminate="true" />
                }
                else
                {
                    <MudSelect @bind-Value="Book" T="string" Label="Livres bibliques">
                        @foreach (var book in BiblesBooks.FrenchCatholic)
                        {
                            <MudSelectItem Value="@book"/>
                        }
                    </MudSelect>

                    <MudNumericField Label="Chapitre" @bind-Value="Chapter" Min="1" Max="1000" />
                    <MudNumericField Label="Verset" @bind-Value="Verse" Min="1" Max="1000" />
                }
                <MudButton @OnClick="@(() => AddVerse)" />
            </MudPaper>
        </MudItem>
    </MudGrid>
</EditForm>

@code {
    CommentDto model = new CommentDto();
    bool Success;
    string Book { get; set; }
    int Chapter { get; set; } = 1;
    int Verse { get; set; } = 1;
    string? ErrorMessage { get; set; } = null;
    bool InProgress { get; set; } = false;
    public int IntValue { get; set; }

    private void OnValidSubmit(EditContext context)
    {
        Success = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private void AddVerse()
    {
        InProgress = true;
        try
        {
            model.Verses += JerusalemBibleService.GetVerse(Book, Chapter, Verse);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        }
        InProgress = false;
    }
}

Here is my static list:
List
public static class BiblesBooks
{
    public static List<string> FrenchCatholic = new List<string>()
    {
        "Genèse",
        "Exode",
        "Lévitique",
        "Nombres",
        "Deutéronome",
        "Josué",
        "Juges",
        "Ruth",
        "1 Samuel",
        "2 Samuel",
        "1 Rois",
        "2 Rois",
        "1 Chroniques",
        "2 Chroniques",
        "Esdras",
        "Néhémie",
        "Tobie",
        "Judith",
        "Esther",
        "1 Maccabées",
        "2 Maccabées",
        "Job",
        "Psaumes",
        "Proverbes",
        "Ecclésiaste",
        "Cantique des Cantiques",
        "Sagesse",
        "Ecclésiastique",
        "Isaïe",
        "Jérémie",
        "Lamentations",
        "Baruch",
        "Ézéchiel",
        "Daniel",
        "Osée",
        "Joël",
        "Amos",
        "Abdias",
        "Jonas",
        "Michée",
        "Nahum",
        "Habacuc",
        "Sophonie",
        "Aggée",
        "Zacharie",
        "Malachie",
        "Matthieu",
        "Marc",
        "Luc",
        "Jean",
        "Actes des Apôtres",
        "Romains",
        "1 Corinthiens",
        "2 Corinthiens",
        "Galates",
        "Éphésiens",
        "Philippiens",
        "Colossiens",
        "1 Thessaloniciens",
        "2 Thessaloniciens",
        "1 Timothée",
        "2 Timothée",
        "Tite",
        "Philémon",
        "Hébreux",
        "Jacques",
        "1 Pierre",
        "2 Pierre",
        "1 Jean",
        "2 Jean",
        "3 Jean",
        "Jude",
        "Apocalypse"
    };
}

Do you have any idea? I do not have any so let me know :)
I want that the MudSelect display the items when I click on it in my page.
Here is the demo:
Demo
Update:
This is working on this page:
@page "/counter"

<MudPopoverProvider />
<MudDialogProvider />
<MudSnackbarProvider />

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<MudText Typo="Typo.h3" GutterBottom="true">Counter</MudText>
<MudText Class="mb-4">Current count: @currentCount</MudText>
<MudButton Color="Color.Primary" Variant="Variant.Filled" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</MudButton>

<MudSelect @bind-Value="Book" T="string" Label="Livres bibliques">
    @foreach (var book in BiblesBooks.FrenchCatholic)
    {
        <MudSelectItem Value="@book" />
    }
</MudSelect>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;
    string Book { get; set; }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}

I do not know why in CommentVerse this is not working? Did I miss something?

What does your MainLayout.razor look like? Is CommentVerse in a class library? And try declaring @rendermode directly on CommentVerse page.

The Mud Providers should be in your main layout instead of in the counter page. This allows all pages that utilize the main layout to have access to the providers instead of specifying them per page as you've done with the counter page.

Including <MudPopoverProvider /> in the component utilizing MudSelect resolved the issue for me.

Doesn't seem to fix for me.

Made my day. Thanks. Btw: did you find any migration docs as MudBlazor API is changing quite quickly? edit: yes, I did, e.g. here: https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/8447
